# PHP PDO::prepare() - SQL Error with placeholders

Tags: sql, pdo, placeholder

My problem is that I can't get placeholders to work in my SQL statements. Specifically, in the below code, when I replace the placeholder `':tripsid'` with a value like `'abcdefg'` the TABLE isn't being created as intended.

SQL Error is:

> **PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax**; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near *''sdfghjk' ( id
>   INT NOT NULL, stop_start SMALLINT NOT NULL, stop_end SMA'* at line 1 )

And the code:

```
// My method to create a table with PDO and placeholders
public function routes_table()  {

    $this->connect();

    $STH = $this->DBH->prepare('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS :tripsid (
        id INT NOT NULL,
        stop_start SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        stop_end SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        distance SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        duration TINYINT NOT NULL,
        medium TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_routes PRIMARY KEY ( id )
        )');


    $tripsid = "sdfghjk";
    $STH->bindParam(':tripsid', $tripsid, PDO::PARAM_STR, 7);

    $STH->execute(); 

    // SQL Errors
    if (!$STH->execute($input)) {
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($STH->errorInfo());
    }

    $this->disconnect();

}
```

I have tried everything I could think of. Does anyone see the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I see this question is over a year old, but I've just stumbled across it and would like to highlight something: **this has nothing to do with the quotation marks.**

When an error occurs and you are given the snippet of SQL relating to the syntax in question, it is automatically enclosed around a pair of single quotation marks. This can often make it look as though there's a different issue, namely that of a mixture of double and single quotes.

In this example -

> **PDO::errorInfo(): Array ( [0] => 42000 [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter) => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax;** check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **''sdfghjk' ( id INT NOT NULL, stop_start SMALLINT NOT NULL, stop_end SMA'** at line 1 )

It's referring to:

```
'sdfghjk' ( id INT NOT NULL, stop_start SMALLINT NOT NULL, stop_end SMA
```

The outermost quotation marks are just specific to the error output; like me - I fear you noticed this and thought your error was about incorrect quotation marks. **This is a red herring!** Remove the outermost single quotes to actually see the SQL which was incorrect.

**As for your real problem: *You CANNOT specify the table name (or a column name) as a parameter*; this is common to prepared statements on most platforms and APIs**. This goes for *any* query - select/insert/update etc etc - none of them can accept the tablename as a parameter. For more information - see this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter).

So with this in mind, I would use `sprintf()` to achieve something like this...

```
$STH = $this->DBH->prepare(
    sprintf('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (
        id INT NOT NULL,
        stop_start SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        stop_end SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        distance SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        duration TINYINT NOT NULL,
        medium TINYTEXT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT pk_routes PRIMARY KEY ( id )
        )', $tripsid) 
);

$STH->execute();
```

Yes, it rather takes the beauty out of PDO when you still have to manipulate strings - unfortunately, this is the case for using table names as parameters! *Also, remember this means 'old stylee' SQL Injection risks could still apply as you are manipulating the query directly.*

I don't expect this will help the OP a year later, but I hope it'll help someone else now! :)

Answer (score 0):

ok now I know that the quotation marks bound to the parameter automatically by PDO::bindParam() is causing the problem. Does anybody have an idea how to remove the **quotation marks from the table name** so my code will be...

```
$STH = $this->DBH->prepare('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tablename (
            id INT NOT NULL,...
```

instead of

```
$STH = $this->DBH->prepare('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'tablename' (
            id INT NOT NULL,
```